# How to override GOOGLE_ENTRYPOINT for my Google Function?

Tags: maven, deployment, google-cloud-functions, multi-module

I am developing serverless applications in Google Cloud using maven as a project build tool. My project has multimodule architecture:

```
root
- post-function
- repost-function-1
- repost-function-2
- repost-function-3
```

Therefore, I need to provide different target paths for each module to deploy them separately. Although I don't see the options of doing that. I am deploying my functions by executing this command from the `root` module:

```
gcloud functions deploy post-function --entry-point io.micronaut.gcp.function.http.HttpFunction --runtime java11 --trigger-http
```

Obviously, it fails, because my root module's `target` doesn't know about children's `target`s. Therefore, I tried to override `GOOGLE_ENTRYPOINT` to use `java -jar post-function/target/post-function-0.1.0.jar` instead of the default autogenerated launch script. However, I've got following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) argument --set-build-env-vars: GOOGLE_ENTRYPOINT is reserved for internal use by GCF deployments and cannot be used.

Hereby, I need another way to specify which target should be used for each function in my project.

Comment: Each module is compiled independently and create its own JAR. Therefore, you need to deploy each module, in each directory. If you want to run the command in the root directory, you can use the `--source=` parameter to specify the folder to upload and to build

Comment: I would like to deploy one module separately, but `mvn build` fails when tries to refer to parent pom (because builder is looking for maven central). Thus, I need to upload all my source modules together. How my `--source` parameter should look like?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to deploy one by one all your functions using a bash script, for example:

```
gcloud functions deploy post-function --trigger-http &
gcloud functions deploy repost-function-1 --trigger-http &
gcloud functions deploy repost-function-2 --trigger-http &
gcloud functions deploy repost-function-3 --trigger-http
```